# Search for a key (that's an invalid character) in an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have some characters as object keys in an object like:


Those are actually icons, and I want to replace one icon with the other.

And my icons object is laid out like this:

```
icons = {
    : {old: , new: }, 
    : {old: , new: }
}
```

How can I search for the icon?
When I try to search, I get an invalid character error.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a syntax error. Why are the icons not in a string? `''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare your [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), put quotes around the keys:

```
const icons = {
  "": { ... } // and so on
};
```

Then you can access it using the bracket notation:

```
icons[""]
```

Comment: Done that. Here's my object, and then if I do console.log(iconList['']); I get undefined.

Comment: Here's the object example.
https://ibb.co/S3m20cS

Comment: Then you probably use the wrong key. You can try this example in your browser's console, it will print 1: let foo = { "大": 1 }; console.log(foo["大"]);

Comment: I think you're right, it works now, thanks!